# OpenCart searching inside of product titles too

Tags: php, opencart

I am using OpenCart.

On my site I am searching the term "Red". I am presented with a number of results such as:

- Red Felt Bag
- Red Laptop Bag
- etc...

But I also get results like:

- Credit Card Cover
- Credit Card Cover Leather
- etc..

This is because the letters 'red' existing inside of the word 'credit'. How can I prevent this and simply search the whole word/term only?

I didn't think to post the entire search.php file as I thought that would be a little much, was targeting those which may know what they need me to copy here to see.

Answer (score 0):

This is because 99.999999% of searches through all of the internet works this way. I understand that you want to provide to your customers the most relevant results only, but you probably forget about the user-friendliness of your web page.

Customers are nowadays used to search for terms like `yes` and expecting the results like `Yes`, `yesterday`, `Yesus`, etc. Or even when they do not know how the word continues and remember only the base of the word and also when more words have the same base, e.g. `Nebula` and `nebulosa` (latin species name of an owl *strix nebulosa*) - they have the same base `nebul`. Now when you apply your desired search modification **no results will be found until the correct words are used**.

But OK, here are the required changes - you need to change two lines in `catalog/model/catalog/product.php` in the method `getProducts()` - find this line (around line 120):

```
$implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
```

and change it to

```
$implode[] = "pd.name = '" . $this->db->escape($word) . "'";
//                    ^- changed LIKE to =
//                       ^- we removed percentage signs -^
```

and then do the same for this line (should be 128)

```
$sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
```

changing to

```
$sql .= " OR pd.description = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "'";
//                          ^- again changed LIKE to =
//                             ^-     again remove percentage signs here     -^
```

After these two changes the search should work like desired (searching only for full words within the product titles and descriptions).